# dsp:getvalueof equivalent in JSP

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, atg-dynamo

What is the equivalent to the following ATG DSP code:

```
<dsp:getvalueof var="age" param="customerAge" scope="request" />
```

Is it

```
Object age = request.getParameter("customerAge")?
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike request attributes, request parameters are always strings, so that should technically be:

```
String age = request.getParameter("customerAge");
```

But in JSP its advisable not to use scriptlets, so using EL you would do it like:

```
<c:set var="age" value="${param.customerAge}" scope="request" />
```